# Web safe fonts not working in emailers for gmail

Tags: gmail, html-email, web-safe-fonts

I am trying to use web safe fonts like:'Tahoma','Lucida','Helvetica' in an emailer for gmail but its not working everything is falling back to 'Arial'. I have tried 'inline css' but still no success but I have seen a mailer from 'Apple' using 'Lucida Grande'...any help will be appreciated

Comment: please provide a sample of the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a font stack using inline CSS, system fonts will display in every version of Gmail (every web browser, every mobile client) provided said font is installed in system. Just like web pages.

```
<td style="font-family: Tahoma, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    Text goes here.
</td>
```

For best results, place the inline font declaration on the **lowest level HTML tag** relative to the text.

✖ Not this:

```
<td style="font-family: Tahoma, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <span style="color: #000000;">
        Text goes here.
    </span>
</td>
```

✔ Instead this:

```
<td>
    <span style="color: #000000; font-family: Tahoma, Lucida, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        Text goes here.
    </span>
</td>
```